# How do I pass modifier flags to archive-file (ar) using CMake with a Ninja generator

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm using CMake with the Ninja generator to generate QNX libraries, and it's creating a `rules.ninja` with rules that look like this:

```
rule CXX_STATIC_LIBRARY_LINKER__<target>
  command = $PRE_LINK && <path>/cmake -E rm -f $TARGET_FILE && <qnx-path>/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-ar qc $TARGET_FILE $LINK_FLAGS $in && <path>/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-ranlib $TARGET_FILE && $POST_BUILD
  description = Linking CXX static library $TARGET_FILE
  restat = $RESTAT
```

and I'd like to add the `D` flag to the `ar` modifiers so that I can get deterministic builds.

like this:

```
...-qnx7.0.0-ar qcD $TARGET_FILE ...
```

Anyone know which CMake variable I need to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to figure it out. The variables to use are `CMAKE_"LANG"_ARCHIVE_CREATE` and `CMAKE_"LANG"_ARCHIVE_APPEND`

Like so:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcD <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
set(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_APPEND "<CMAKE_AR> qD <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcD <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_APPEND "<CMAKE_AR> qD <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```